# IOS, Xcode: capture UITouch event ended

Tags: ios, xcode, view, uitouch

I am a beginner in IOS programming...I am not familiar with the methods at this moment.
The setting is:
   I have a function called. In this function, I would like to wait for one tap and then generate a new ViewController. I only need the CGPoint of tap and then move on to the next steps. But I don't know if there is some method which could capture touchesEnded. Or maybe I think in the wrong way. Could anyone provide me some ?

If I create the new viewController just after the touch ended, then nothing is happen after the modelDetect(it's required). The application will end before get a touch.

So I have no idea now.

Really thanks a lot.

```
- (void)modelDetect
{
 //wait for touches....then
 [self addNewViewController]; 
}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event  
{
   NSLog(@"touch happens");
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   Location = [touch locationInView:self.view];      
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using `UITapGestureRecognizer` it could solve your issue

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(userTapped:)];
[self addGestureRecognizer:rec];


- (void)userTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if(recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized)
    {
        CGPoint point = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view]; 
        // point.x and point.y  touch coordinates
         NSLog("%lf %lf", point.x, point.y);

        // here you could call your method or add the new view controller which you want
         [self addNewViewController]; 
    }
}
```

For getting the point through `touchesEnded` you should  use CGPoint

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *aTouch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint point = [aTouch locationInView:self];
    // point.x and point.y touch coordinates
    NSLog("%lf %lf", point.x, point.y);
}
```